# Does anyone know how I can send an email to all registered users in my online store?

Tags: magento

Does anyone know how I can send an email to all registered users in my online store? I created the template as a transactional mail, but i don´t know how to send this email to all registered users

Comment: @Reflective The question is marked with the `magento` tag, so maybe you should look before getting all sarcastic. Also, there is nothing lazy about not knowing how to proceed, that's what this site is for.

Answer (score 3):

1. In the Admin panel, select **Customers > Manage Customers**. Click
2. Click **Refresh Filter** to display all your customers.
3. Click **select all**
4. From the **Actions field** in the top right of this page, select
   **Subscribe to Newsletter**.
5. Click **Submit**

All registered customers are now subscribed to your newsletter. Now you can create a newsletter template at Newsletter / Newsletter Templates.

1. After creating and saving the template you can schedule it by selecting **Queue     Newsletter** in the Action pull down.
2. Select a date and time at **Queue Date Start** you want to start sending your newsletter.
3. Click on **Save Newsletter** and you will see the scheduled newsletter at the Newsletter Queue.
4. If every thing goes right you will see that after a while all the recipients will receive the newsletter and the status should be **Sent**

If you don't want to subscribe all customers to the newsletter, you can use this extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketing/email-marketing/mass-email-to-registered-customers-7187.html

Comment: Believed to have classified the question within Magento. Yes, yes I have newsletter. Anyway I have solved the problem I know I can only send emails to those who subscribe to the newsletter for violating the law on data protection. Thank you very much alike.